# PHP Timezone shown in phpinfo() is not working

Tags: php, apache, timezone

I installed some time ago XAMPP, when php7 was released I change it manually

Now with phpinfo() I'm getting that my php.ini is located in:
[image]

Both, in my /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini and in screen shown by phpinfo() I have:
[image]

My problem is that It doesn't matter what I write in the php.ini variable **date.timezone**, when I restart my server the information in phpinfo() is **correctly** updated, but if I echo `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` I allways shows the UTC time

```
<?php 
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ."<br/>"; //Outputs 2016-06-09 19:58:35 Incorrect.... My default timezone is America/Mexico_City
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ."<br/>";  //Outputs 2016-06-09 20:58:35 //Correct
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //Outputs 2016-06-09 14:58:35 Correct, the first echo should have shown this
?>
```

I've looked for any others php.ini files in my system and I've change the timezone for America7Mexico_City in all of them, then I've restarted my server but nothing changes

Any Idea?....If this is helpful when I manually installed php7, it was downloaded in /usr/src/php7 but inside there isn't any php.ini file

Thanks in advance